# How to access a specific value in a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
upatients = {
    'Junipero':[ 37, 114, 'M', 'I', 6, 2],
    'Sunita':[22, 27, 'F', 'B', 9, 5],
    'Issur':[ 38, 48, 'D', 'W', 4, 1],
    'Luitgard':[ 20, 105, 'M', 'L', 1, 4],
    'Rudy':[ 20, 27, 'D', 'O', 9, 5],
    'Ioudith':[ 19, 93, 'D', 'I', 4, 3]
}

for key in upatients:
    patients = key
    print(patients)
```

I am trying to access the values in the `[5]` position in the list and sort the list based on those values. I am having trouble printing those values.

Comment: What list are you trying to sort?

Comment: After the first loop, `patients` is just the last key in `upatients`. It's not a list.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to sort the patient names based on the [5] value of the lists that are assigned to the dictionary keys.

Comment: You may want to comment out / delete the line with the second `for` loop.

Comment: @PM77-1 What's wrong with the indentation? The second loop isn't intended to be nested.

Comment: try this. patients = sort(upatients.keys()) for sorted patients.

Comment: @Bamar - After the latest edit - no problem with indentation..

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` option to `sorted()` to use an element of the value when sorting.

```
def sort_dict_keys(d, index):
    return sorted(d, key = lambda p: d[p][index])

print(sort_dict_keys(upatients, 5))
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you turn this into a function? Just so I can be flexible

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: how would i sort the result by another index if i wanted to?

Comment: The index is a parameter to the function, so you can sort by any index.

Answer (score 1):

To print the item at the 5th index in each list you can use:

```
for key in upatients:
    patients = upatients[key]
    print(patients[5])
```

Here is one way of getting a sorted list of patients:

```
tmp = [(upatients[key][5], key) for key in upatients]
sort(tmp)
new_list = [x[1] for x in tmp]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Issur', 'Junipero', 'Ioudith', 'Luitgard', 'Rudy', 'Sunita']
```